# What is a word for "to make scary"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word for "to make scary" or "to make something scary."  I don't want a word for scaring someone.  Here are examples:

They _________ their house for Halloween.

The staff _________ the haunted house.

The owners had _________ the area, which caused the kids to be frightened.

Comment: I gave this a lot of thought a few years ago, and failed to come up with an answer in the lexis.

Comment: Perhaps  *decorated* works instead - especially for the first sentence as Halloween decorations are implicitly scarey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suffix *-fy* means to make or become: *beautify*, *simplify*, *liquefy*.

So you could add *-fy* to an appropriate adjective. *Scary* would be problematic because *scarify* means to make scarred (as in marks on the skin), rather than make scary.

*Spookify* maybe?

Comment: Have you any evidence that the addition of -_fy_ is always licensed? Productivity is not ungradable, though some seem to think it is. I can't find 'spookify' in any dictionary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, licensed by whom? How do I apply for such a license?

Comment: Wordness is better judged by usage panels who monitor how frequently candidate words are used in various corpora than by people spotting a lexical gap  and suggesting a D-I-Y patch. / You'd need to get a job with OED say, but you'd still be peer-monitored.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, do you have any evidence that "wordness" is licensed? Let me get the process straight: People invent a new word (e.g. "selfie"), but it's not actually a "licensed" word until some usage panel somewhere makes the observation that sufficient people are using this word, but you are saying that people shouldn't be using the word until it is licensed. To become licensed, the word has to be used, but it shouldn't be used until it is licensed. Do you see a problem there?